# Create an array which contains elements of other arrays

Tags: arrays, c

Lets say I have two arrays, A[5] and B[3]. I want to create another array C[8] that will contain all the elements from A and B. First it will store A elements and then B. I am a beginner in C. So anyone can help?

Comment: Do you want a [shallow copy or a deep copy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copying)? Do you need to differentiate the ones that came from `A` from `B`?

Comment: Dont need to differentiate. Just need order. First A and then B.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `memcpy`. Below I have assumed these are arrays of `int`s, but you could replace `sizeof(int)` with the type you are actually doing.

```
memcpy(C, A, 5 * sizeof(int));
memcpy(C + 5, B, 3 * sizeof(int));
```

The first line says copy 5 ints from the start of A to the start of C. The second line says copy 3 ints from the start of B to C starting at index 5.

Edit: As pointed out in the comments, I overcomplicated this. You can use the following and not have to worry about types:

```
memcpy(C, A, 5 * sizeof(C[0]));
memcpy(C + 5, B, 3 * sizeof(C[0]));
```

Comment: now you have an exapmle why it is better to use sizeof object not types. `memcpy(C,A,5*sizeof(C[0]));` and it does not matter what types the arrays are.

Comment: Thanks for the better example. In retrospect my original answer was kind of dumb.

Comment: You could also just use `sizeof(A)` and `sizeof(B)`without multiplying.

Comment: @Barmar dangerous. If B & A are pointers (for example dynamic arrays) then it will not work for sure. Better avoid

Comment: True, but we're told that they're arrays, not pointers.

Comment: This answer is good and fast. If you want to get rid of the magic number on the second copy, `memcpy(C + sizeof A / sizeof *A, B, sizeof B)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with two for loops. First copy the content from A to C:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    C[i] = A[i];
```

And then, copy the content of B to C, from the position where you inserted the last element of A:

```
for(int i = 5; i < 8; i++)
   C[i] = B[i-5];
```

Note that the loop now starts with 5 and ends in 8, this is because we want to start copying the values of B into C after the positions already filled with the values of A. The position of B where we are reading is `i - 5`, which gives the positions 0, 1, 2... for B. We are doing this here because the loop starts in 5.

You can also do this with just one for loop in the following way:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    C[i] = A[i];
    if(i < 3)
        C[i+5] = B[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

universal function

```
void *copy(void * restrict dest, const void * restrict src, const void * restrict src1, const size_t len1, const size_t len2, const size_t elemsize)
{
    unsigned char *restrict ucdest = dest;

    if(dest && src && src1)
    {
        memcpy(ucdest, src, elemsize * len1);
        memcpy(ucdest + elemsize * len1, src1, elemsize * len2);
    }
    return dest;
}
```